# Azure function ExceptionHandling

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function and I'm not sure if it throws an exception or not when it runs. I have a try and catch block and throw the exception in the Function itself but all runs are shown as succeeded. Where would I find the errors/exceptions of an Azure function and how can I log it in the best way possible?

Best regards
Manuel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best approach would be if you could add Application Insights to your Azure Functions. You could monitor in real time or also search for Failures. If that is not possible, you can enable log stream and check over there:

More info:

https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip30.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring